# What do I need to do to finish this outside-door install properly?

Tags: doors, garage, exterior, siding

A new steel door was installed to our unfinished garage but I am not satisfied with how it currently looks. The previous door had trim covering the gap between the siding and the door, as well as the bottom between the riser and the concrete pad.

Is this what is typically done? or is there a better approach to take to this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a PVC trim molding glued to the metal frame and fitted against the siding J-Channel.  On the bottom, again, pick out a PVC trim piece. A quarter round or stop trim would work. That can be nailed and glued. Use small galvanized or stainless steel nails.

Answer (score 1):

Normally at that point there would be a capping trim fitted and job done, though maybe more filler should be added.